# Twitter Bootstrap grid Vertical align bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been at this what seems forever and can't figure it out. I have a grid with content of different heights due to images, and I am trying to get them all to align bottom but have had no luck. I have tried what I have seen on here, but nope, commented in my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qXT6K

Comment: Can you explain more what youre trying to do, you want .sizes blocks row aligned to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an updated version of your fiddle with (what I think) you want: http://jsfiddle.net/qXT6K/34/

You were on the right track with `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`; it's just a matter of getting the offsets right.

I have given the container div a height just to show the bottom-alignment. You do need to give it a height, otherwise with all its children absolutely positioned, it will default to 0.

To center the container div (and so have all its children appear centered), you need to use `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` (shorthand `margin: 0 auto`), plus a set width on the div (applied through the class `span8` in my example), plus removal of the `float` property which is bundled into all `span-`classed elements. You also need `padding-right: 40px` to center the container's children, accounting for the `margin-left: 20px` which is also applied to `.span-`s.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/UxYnV/

**Update**
Now elements are centered: http://jsfiddle.net/UxYnV/2/

Comment: Pretty much that is what I am attempting but in your example it is no longer centered

Comment: So I tried this on my test site just to see and it just align to the bottom of the document window. I think that is why available needs to be positioned relative to get those elements to stay in the same area.

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe giving more detail would help us help you... you wanted the elements aligned at the bottom, they are... what exactly do you want now? Do you have a url we can checkout or something? Maybe a full example would help us understand exactly your needs.

Comment: Ok I will try this again, sorry I am horrible at explaining it. div.sizes needs to be within div.available, I have elements above and below div.available I would like to have div.sizes as they display now, but the content of them to be bottom aligned to div.available. hopefully that will help a little.