# Bootstrap 3 Align Text To Bottom of Div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a setup in Bootstrap that would look something like this, where I have text aligned with the bottom of an image:

```
================================================
|                                              |
|    ####################                      |
|    ##THIS IS AN IMAGE##                      |
|    ####################   ...And some text!  |
|                                              |
================================================
```

So I tried this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="~/Images/MyLogo.png" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Some Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I end up with something that looks more like this, where the text is top-aligned:

```
================================================
|                                              |
|    ####################  ...And some text!   |
|    ##THIS IS AN IMAGE##                      |
|    ####################                      |
|                                              |
================================================
```

I've tried a few positioning tricks to get it to work, but when I do that, it breaks the mobile-firstness of Bootstrap. When collapsed down to phone-size, I need it to snap to this:

```
==========================
|                        |
|  ####################  |
|  ##THIS IS AN IMAGE##  |
|  ####################  |
|                        |
|   ...And some text!    |
|                        |
==========================
```

So doing it as a table really isn't an option.

**EDIT:** Here's a fiddle, courtesy of Joseph Marikle in the comments :D  http://jsfiddle.net/6WvUY/1/

Comment: for those of you who are trying to experiment with this, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6WvUY/1/

Comment: Does your image have a fixed height?

Comment: This question really old but in Bootsrap 4, there is now `align-bottom`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use a combination of absolute and relative positioning.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PKVza/2/

given your html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="~/Images/MyLogo.png" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-align-text col-sm-6">
        <h3>Some Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

use the following CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px ) {
  .row {
      position: relative;
  }

  .bottom-align-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

EDIT - Fixed CSS and JSFiddle for mobile responsiveness and changed the ID to a class.

Comment: I prefer classes to id for things like this, but this is the best I could come up with too.

Comment: I also agree with @JosephMarikle that a class would be better than an ID, as it would be reusable on the page.

Comment: Is there a reason why .row needs to be global? I added an extra class to the definition such as `.bottom-align.row` so it only affects that row, rather than all rows on the page.

Comment: @redfox05 -- there's not a good reason for that. Your solution is a good one if you don't want it applied to all `.row`'s

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

CSS:

```
#container {
    height:175px;
}

#container h3{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="//placehold.it/600x300" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
    <div id="container" class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>Some Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: add the <

Answer (score 7):

I collected some ideas from other SO question (largely from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12847522/3346612) and [this css page](http://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/))

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WvUY/6/)

The idea is to use relative and absolute positioning to move your line to the bottom:

```
@media (min-width: 768px ) {
.row {
    position: relative;
}

#bottom-align-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }}
```

The `display:flex` option is at the moment a solution to make the div get the same size as its parent. This breaks on the other hand the bootstrap possibilities to auto-linebreak on small devices by adding `col-sx-12` class. (This is why the media query is needed)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/6WvUY/7/.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="//placehold.it/600x300" alt="Logo" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: table;
}

.row > div {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score -14):

The easiest way I have tested just add a `<br>` as in the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <br><h3><p class="text-center">Some Text</p></h3>
</div>
```

The only problem is that a extra line break (generated by that `<br>`) is generated when the screen gets smaller and it stacks. But it is quick and simple.

Comment: This is a BAD solution, it won't align properly if height isn't exactly one line.