# Bootstrap: align element to bottom doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem similar to this one:

[Bootstrap 3 Align Text To Bottom of Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539197/bootstrap-3-align-text-to-bottom-of-div)

Except that its proposed solution doesn't work in my case. My HTML is:

```html
<header class="masthead">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" alt="My Logo"></a>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-right" id="nav_derecha">
            <ul id="lang">
                <li><a href=""><img src="es.png" alt="Español"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="en.png" alt="English"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="fr.png" alt="Français"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="de.png" alt="Deutsch"></a></li>
            </ul>           
            <ul id="login_area">
                Login | Register
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>          
</header>
```

And my CSS is:

```css
header.masthead {
    background-color: #103961;
    height: 82px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}    
header.masthead nav {
    background: #339966;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    /* max-width: 1100px; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}    
.navbar-brand > img {
    width: 270px;
}


@media only screen and ( min-width: 768px ) {
    #nav_derecha {
        position: relative;
        }
    #login_area {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}

#login_area li a{
    color:white !important;  
}

#lang  li {
    display: inline;
    }
```

Using the "position:absolute" trick, the login/register links appear right on top of the language bar. I want the language bar to appear on the upper-right corner, and the login area below it, aligned to the bottom of the header. How can I do this?

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/wxd5dtf9/ - do you get any errors in your console? (I removed the images for the demo)

Comment: @ochi: well, I don't understand it. Here is a Bootply I just made, where it doesn't work: http://www.bootply.com/Ug9WgACx86

Comment: updated your bootply... it's very strage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this, is what you are looking for:

```
.nav-holder{
   display:inline-block;   
   vertical-align:top;
}

#lang{
   -webkit-padding-start: 0; 
   margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1w6xr92j/7/

Need to make block elements inline-block elements, so that they sit side by side.

Also, I saw some padding that webkit was putting on the ul by default, so I took that off.

Aligning vertically to the top is all we needed to get the links to sit up at the top.

edit: positioning your masthead relatively, and then your container fluid, absolutely, will contain your links as you want. You can then also set your "right" property so that the container sits however far away from the right side you want.

If you would like anything else clarified, just let me know.

Comment: In your fiddle, the language bar and the login area aren't aligned to the right. Plus, if I maximize the browser screen, the login area disappears.

Comment: @PaulJ, I've edited the fiddle, along with the answer above to alleviate the issues you've pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but one thing: `.container-fluid` is one of the built-in classes in Bootstrap. Won't it affect the rest of the page to mess with it?

Comment: Good catch. Since css supports multiple classes, just apply the styles to a different class name, and append that class to your element.

Comment: I've been playing with your solution, and it has the same problem than the previous one: the login area isn't aligned with the bottom of the header.

Comment: thanks. Looks like it works now. One question: the last change you've made has been pretty much add a `height` to `navbar_right`so that it spans the entire height of the header, right?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely positioned elements don't effect their parent's height.

Comment: @PaulJ, if you're interested in learning more about the css box model, and how positioning and many other aspects of css work together, this is a pretty good resource. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Visual_formatting_model

Answer (score 2):

I changed two sections of your CSS to this:

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 768px ) {
    #nav_derecha {
        position: relative;
        }
    #login_area {
        position: absolute;
          text-align: right; /* used to say bottom:0; right: 0 -> you can remove this line too, if you wish */
    }
}

#login_area{ /* there is no li a  inside this ul, so I removed them from the css */
    color:white !important;  
}
```

**[See updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7zU70hDWgB)**

Comment: Thanks, but with this solution, the login area still isn't aligned to the bottom of the header.