# bootstraps 3 align bottom with 3 column in row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I've seen this thread but its for 2 column (col-md-6) and I've tried the jsfidlle too for 3 column but column 1st and column 2nd become stack.

[Bootstrap 3 Align Text To Bottom of Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539197/bootstrap-3-align-text-to-bottom-of-div)

what I want for my project is

```css
.row {
      position: relative;
  }

 .bottom-align-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="bottom-align-text col-sm-4">
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="//placehold.it/600x300" alt="Logo" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-align-text col-sm-4">
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to make them both align bottom?

Comment: you have to increase or decrease the value of `bottom` or `right`

Comment: Try including vertical-align: bottom; in your css??

Answer (score 1):

`flexbox` can do that

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flexy {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.flexy .bottom-align-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;

}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flexy">
    <div class="bottom-align-text col-sm-4">
      <h3>Some Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x300" alt="Logo" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-align-text col-sm-4">
      <h3>Some Text</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `column 1st` and `column 2nd` in to a `row` then we'll have 2 columns structure. See my jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/robinhuy/kg1ykfL1/3/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes