# Bootstrap 3 bottom vertically align image and link with link pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I am hoping someone can help me with this one Bootstrap question as I am stumped.

I have been asked to bottom vertically align an image and a link with an image inside of it.

The problem I am facing is they also want the link to have `pull-right` on the link/image combo, which kills most of the vertical-align classes out there as they rely on `float:none`, and pull-right requires `float:right`

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- start of container -->

  <!-- Left side sub-navbar goes here (not important) -->

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1"> <!-- start of section -->

    <div class="row"> <!-- start of outer-most row -->

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">  

        <div class="row"> <!-- start of title row -->
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:5px;"><strong>TITLE GOES HERE</strong></h1>
             <hr class="tall">
          </div>
        </div> <!-- end of title row -->

        <div class="row"> <!-- start of image/link row -->

          <!-- left image -->
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54b97771e4b06f2c55eba94a/55be4ee1e4b0830374d48fb2/55be4f25e4b06dfa42778e26/1438535461984/4.jpg?format=300w">
          </div>

          <!-- link/image combo -->
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pull-right">
            <a href="/" target="_blank">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://teamhalprin.com/portfolio/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Hummer-logo-350x48.png">
            </a>
          </div>         

        </div> <!-- end of image/link row -->

      </div> <!-- end of outer-most row -->

    </div> <!-- end of section -->


</div> <!-- end of container -->
```

And here is a BootPly I made for those that like pretty pictures: http://www.bootply.com/eiEPXErfJx

P.S. Sorry if my bootstrap code is bloated with extra `row`'s and `col-*`'s, I am still learning it.

Although I accepted that answer, it doesn't work perfectly on mobile devices. The best fix I have found so far is to change the col-* classes on the left image and link/image combo divs as follows:

```
<!-- left image -->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54b97771e4b06f2c55eba94a/55be4ee1e4b0830374d48fb2/55be4f25e4b06dfa42778e26/1438535461984/4.jpg?format=300w">
</div>

<!-- link/image combo -->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 bottom-align-text">
    <a href="/" target="_blank">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://teamhalprin.com/portfolio/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Hummer-logo-350x48.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

This will force the buttons to be next to each other even when on mobile to make sure the button doesn't overlay the left image and hide the bottom of it

Latest code:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- start of container -->

  <!-- Left side sub-navbar goes here (not important) -->

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1"> <!-- start of section -->

    <div class="row"> <!-- start of outer-most row -->

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">  

        <div class="row"> <!-- start of title row -->
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:5px;"><strong>TITLE GOES HERE</strong></h1>
             <hr class="tall">
          </div>
        </div> <!-- end of title row -->

        <div class="row"> <!-- start of image/link row -->

          <!-- left image -->
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54b97771e4b06f2c55eba94a/55be4ee1e4b0830374d48fb2/55be4f25e4b06dfa42778e26/1438535461984/4.jpg?format=300w">
          </div>

          <!-- link/image combo -->
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 bottom-align-text">
            <a href="/" target="_blank">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://teamhalprin.com/portfolio/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Hummer-logo-350x48.png">
            </a>
          </div>         

        </div> <!-- end of image/link row -->

      </div> <!-- end of outer-most row -->

    </div> <!-- end of section -->


</div> <!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: Do you want to align both items at the bottom or do you have an image of the desired result?

Comment: Yes I would like the hummer logo's bottom to align with the bottom of the iron man photo. All I need to do is figure out how to move the hummer logo down while still being responsive, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out

Comment: Ah, yeah I missed a few on the section, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a class to the div row that contains the context that should be aligned to the bottom:

```
.row {
      position: relative;
  }

 .bottom-align-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

html:

```
<div class="row .... bottom-align-text" ..>
```

http://www.bootply.com/EbPZrjAw5w

[image]

Read also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24539629/1165509

Comment: BTW, grid layout column design include the larger ones, so if you specify a size for xs it would set the same size for all bigger columns, unless you specify other sizes for the bigger ones.

Answer (score 0):

*****You need to make one Image as absolute and other relative to overlap each other
Here is the sample of the Same code

---

**Try using more of bootstrap tags**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" >
            <h1 style="margin-bottom:5px;"><strong>TITLE GOES HERE</strong></h1>
            <hr class="short">
          </div>
         
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <img class="img-responsive"  style="position:absolute;margin:auto;border: 1px solid red; width: 60%;left: 20%;top: 20%;margin-top:20%" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54b97771e4b06f2c55eba94a/55be4ee1e4b0830374d48fb2/55be4f25e4b06dfa42778e26/1438535461984/4.jpg?format=300w">
        
           <img class="img-responsive" style="relative; width:100%" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54b97771e4b06f2c55eba94a/55be4ee1e4b0830374d48fb2/55be4f25e4b06dfa42778e26/1438535461984/4.jpg?format=300w"></a>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</div></div>
            <div id="push"></div>
```