# Bootstrap CSS Bottom Class Not Working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I want the message to lay on top of the background image.  I would like the message to be fixed/stuck so it aligns with the bottom of the background image container.  Bottom:0; doesn't seem to do anything.  I need it to be responsive, so I can't set a fixed pixel amount to the bottom class.  Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
.bg-img {
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
}
.bg-img img {
    width: 100%;
}
.message {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(232,218,193,0.03);
}

<section class="full-image-desc">
<div class="container-fluid message">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>Sub-Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum augue vitae magna ultricies, sit amet fermentum risus fringilla. Donec arcu eros, suscipit ut ornare id, tincidunt eget nisl. Pellentesque non massa quis nibh rutrum tempor a eget nisl. Vestibulum ut laoreet nulla, id posuere lectus. Nulla id est ligula. Mauris vitae ipsum sed metus eleifend interdum at ac tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur vel eleifend augue, eget consectetur purus. Sed imperdiet pulvinar urna at porta.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bg-img">
   <img src="img/background-image.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Align Text To Bottom of Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539197/bootstrap-3-align-text-to-bottom-of-div?s=1|3.0134)

Answer (score 0):

To make it responsive you'll need meta data to tell the browser what it should look like on each platform (Desktop, tablet, or phone). As for the text to be on top of the image they'll need to be in the same div.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8" background="img/background-image.jpg">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h2>Sub-Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum augue vitae magna ultricies, sit amet fermentum risus fringilla. Donec arcu eros, suscipit ut ornare id, tincidunt eget nisl. Pellentesque non massa quis nibh rutrum tempor a eget nisl. Vestibulum ut laoreet nulla, id posuere lectus. Nulla id est ligula. Mauris vitae ipsum sed metus eleifend interdum at ac tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur vel eleifend augue, eget consectetur purus. Sed imperdiet pulvinar urna at porta.</p>
        </div>
```

This can also be done in css

```
div {
    background-image: url("img/background-image.jpg");
}
```

I would suggest the css way as it'll make things easier to find in the long run.