# How to align div to bottom inside div with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
html, body, .sidebar-container, .sidebar-row {
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #2C3544;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        display: block;
        background-color: #2C3544;
    }
}
img{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
.sidebar-image{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.sidebar-items{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid sidebar-container">
    <div class="row sidebar-row">
        <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-12 sidebar-image">
                    <img src="assets/logo-white.png" width="75px" height="75px"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row sidebar-items">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dashboard</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Projects</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Statistics</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row align-bottom">
                hafldjalfjsdlfsjdlfsjlfs
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2 content">
            Main Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wrote this HTML/CSS code trying to align a div to the bottom inside another div:

I want to align this last div in the `col-md-2` to the bottom of the `sidebar-container` which height is 100%. I tried adding the bootstrap class `align-bottom` but somehow this doesn't work. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Align Text To Bottom of Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539197/bootstrap-3-align-text-to-bottom-of-div)

Comment: @Rob Nah this is aligning a div inside a div not text to bottom of a div

Comment: The text is inside a div but there are a number of other duplicates of your question. Did you search SO before posting?

Comment: @Rob It's not about the text, it's about aligin the DIV inside the other DIV to the bottom. Yes I searched SO

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Suppose you have 2 divs. Div A(Outer) and Div B(Inner). To achieve your task just place Div B code in Div A code and in Div B css class add this

```
position : absolute
bottom   : 0
```

Comment: Problem: But then the inner Div is no longer centered. It will go to the bottom left.

Comment: So if you are using `bootstrap4` so just add the class `justify-content-center` on outer div. This will center the inner div

Comment: This worked for me with bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 30):

You can also just use bootstrap flexbox to do this.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column bg-success" style="height: 200px;">
  <div class="mb-auto p-2">Flex item-1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item-2</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item-3</div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex align-items-end flex-column bg-info" style="height: 200px;">
  <div class="p-2">Flex item-a</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item-b</div>
  <div class="mt-auto p-2">Flex item-c</div>
</div>
```

**align items to the left or right** make sure that you include the entire `d-flex align-items-end flex-column` on the parent element and choose start or end depending if you want it to be aligned left or right.

**align item to the bottom** Then, use `mt-auto` on the div that you want to stick to the bottom of the parent.

Comment: Is there a way to make this but align to the center of the parent div?

Comment: The documentation doesn't give an option for aligning in the middle but you could try justify-content-center. I feel like that might not work though. Would need to see your code to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

When using Bootstrap grid system, my go-to solution is like this:

- add `d-flex` to each `col-*`
- add `d-flex flex-column` to each `card-body`
- add `mt-auto mx-auto` to the last element (or last *div* of elements) I want to stick to the end

This prevents any further styling mess-up in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

**Relevant Documentation:**

1. Flex Alignment in Bootstrap 5.0: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#align-items
2. Vertical Alignment in Bootstrap 5.0: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/vertical-align/

**Relevant Code:**
What worked for me to align a div (of text) at the bottom of a row/container

```
<div class="d-flex align-content-end flex-wrap mb-2">
    <span class="display-4 fw-bold text-black text-start mt-0 mb-0">Active Mural Projects</span>
</div>
```