# How to put a div to the to buttom on boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <h1>Product</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <hr class="w-100" size="5" />
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <h3>price €</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <hr class="w-100" size="5" />
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <p class="lead">ART_DESIGNATION</p>
  </div>
  <div class="align-text-bottom">
    <div class="cell">
      <form class="position-fixed" action="" method="GET">
        <div style="display: inline;">
          <label>Quantité </label>
          <input style="" type="number" placeholder="1" class="form-control">
          <button style="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter au panier</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Web page :

[image]

I would like to put the form (label, input, button) in 1 line and to the bottom of the  like this :

[image]

But I can't do it

Can you help me ?

I try to use bootsrap class for put buttom and also make my own CSS property but either it doesn't give a correct result or it doesn't do anything... I try to do tha this post say but that do nothing for me and i didnt want to up an old post : [How to align div to bottom inside div bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877347/how-to-align-div-to-bottom-inside-div-bootstrap)

Comment: `echo '<div class="align-text-bottom"';` is missing a closing `>` for the `<div>`.

Comment: actually I had forgotten that, but it just aligned with the top text and not put in bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Bootstrap grid properly.

See the snippet below.

```css
.col-6 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img class="w-100 h-100" src="https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row align-self-end h-100">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="cell">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h1>Product</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <hr class="w-100" size="5" />
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <h3>price €</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <hr class="w-100" size="5" />
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          <p class="lead">ART_DESIGNATION</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-end">
        <div class="cell">
          <form action="" method="GET">
            <div style="display: inline;">
              <label>Quantité </label>
              <input style="" type="number" placeholder="1" class="form-control">
              <button style="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter au panier</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That work, thanx you verry much ! I understand now how to use table on bootsrap